# Convert DataFrame to String in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the format in an excel (there are many more names):

| Student Name |
| --- |
| John Martin |
| Steve Johnson |
| Alice Cramer |
| Lisa Green |
| Chandler Hans |

.
.
.

I have to put these names in an SQL Query for which I need them to be in the following format as a string:

'John Martin','Steve Johnson','Alice Cramer','Lisa Green','Chandler Hans'

My Approach:

```
students<-read_xlsx("students.xlsx")
students<-paste0(students,collapse=",")
```

This doesn't work as this gives reverse slashes in the output (\). Even using shQuote gives reverse slashes.

If I declare it directly I get the required input which works in the SQL query,
(just an example, I cannot use this as names are changing constantly)

```
students<-c('John Martin','Steve Johnson','Alice Cramer','Lisa Green','Chandler Hans')
students<-toString(sprintf("'%s'",students)
```

Is there a way to go about it ?

Comment: This doesn't work as the backslashes still remain

Comment: Where do they remain? That line of code should remove all back slashes from array. Either way, I posted an answer with another option.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dput`.  see

```r
dput(rownames(mtcars))
#> c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", 
#> "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", 
#> "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", 
#> "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", 
#> "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic", "Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", 
#> "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", 
#> "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", 
#> "Ferrari Dino", "Maserati Bora", "Volvo 142E")
```

So if you have a vector say `students`, then

```r
dput(students)
#> c("John Martin", "Steve Johnson", "Alice Cramer", "Lisa Green", 
#> "Chandler Hans")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't work as this gives backslashes

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
paste0("'",students,"'",collapse = ",")
```

Output:

```
[1] "'John Martin','Steve Johnson','Alice Cramer','Lisa Green','Chandler Hans'"
```

---

Data used:

```
students<-c('John Martin','Steve Johnson','Alice Cramer',
            'Lisa Green','Chandler Hans')

> students
[1] "John Martin"   "Steve Johnson" "Alice Cramer"  "Lisa Green"    "Chandler Hans"
```

Comment: "'c(\"John Martin\", \"Steve Johnson\", \"Alice Cramer\", \"Lisa Green\", \"Chandler Hans\")'"
               
I am getting this as the output
If I try 

gsub("\\\\","",students)
        
I still get this only

(appreciate your help)

Comment: Can you please `dput()` your dataset (or at least, `head`) after you do `students<-read_xlsx("students.xlsx")`? Otherwise it is hard to help you since I don't know where the back slashes are coming from.

Comment: My answer does solve it for a character vector so maybe the problem is reading the Excel file or turning it into an array/matrix/data.frame...